# How can I run a main function inside a project dependency from within Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

In Eclipse, when you do `Run As`->`Java Application`, it brings up a list of every Class on the whole classpath with a `public static void main` function in it.  If I've got a JAR file on the classpath, I can run a main out of some class in that JAR file.

Can I do this same thing within Netbeans?  In Netbeans, when I right click a project and choose `Run`, it only seems to show me classes within that project, and not all the dependencies.

Comment: Right click on the main class in question and choose "Run file"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't have the .java file for the class though, so the only place I can see the class is under `dependencies`.  I tried expanding foo.jar and right clicking on the Main class.  Alas, there is no "Run file" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Add your main class in the Project Properties (shown below) and then run your project**

1. Right click your project
2. Select properties
3. Enter full package and class name under Main Class
4. Click the OK button
5. Right click on the project and choose Run

[image]

Comment: I will as soon as the time limit expires (can't accept answer for another ~5 mins), thanks!  In the mean time, would you mind editing it a bit to include the steps in the text?  The picture is a little tough to see, but I recognized the dialog and realized what you were saying.